# program has stopped in AVD

Tags: java, android

i make a button to start a game. whenever i click on that button from AVD, unfortunately the program has stopped and i am new to android programming. i try googling my problem and it seems there is something wrong with the code. can anyone help me? i also share a link to my code, visit https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hyitjbgda69rkd4/3Iz8WuM5-5

the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    private Game game1;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Perform action on click
                game1 = new Game(this);
                setContentView(game1);
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Game class :

```
public Game(OnClickListener onClickListener) 
    {
        super((Context) onClickListener);

        caneta = new Paint();

        this.caneta.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        this.caneta.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.caneta.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        this.caneta.setStrokeWidth(5);

        l = this.getWidth();
        a = this.getHeight();

        singlesquare = new Cell[x][y];

        int xss = l / x;
        int yss = a / y;

        for (int z = 0; z < y; z++) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
            {
                singlesquare[z][i] = new Empty(xss * i, z * yss);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be calling `setContentView()` more than once. Is that the line that's causing the error? Further, the object type of `game1` doesn't appear to be a View.